# Google Map won't load on SharePoint 2010 web part

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3, sharepoint-2010

I have a web part that will get locations and then display the markers on a Google Map. For now I'm just trying to get a map to display on the page but that's not even working. Here is the code I placed into the aspx file:

```
    <div id="LocationWebPart">
    <h3>Locations:</h3>
    <hr />
    <div id="LocationMap" style="width:250px;height:300;"></div>
    <div id="locations">
    </div>
    <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/_layouts/website/scripts/gmap3.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#LocationMap').gmap3( {
            actions: 'init',
            options: {
                center: [41.896254, -86.621529],
                zoom: 11
                }
            });
        });
</script> 
</div>
```

When I run that in a test.html it works fine. Firebug also shows that the gmap3.min.js script is there.

Also, replacing `$(document).ready()` with `_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push()` doesn't do anything either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. I forgot the `px` after `height:300;">`

Comment: That's the answer to the question. I should have stated that, sorry.

Comment: Ah, no problem - don't forget to accept this as the answer when you can, in that case!